# filling multidimensional array using variable values and nested loops

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Essentially, I have a xyz generator but I need to be able to store it and recall the values later. My issue is that my values are doubles and I indicated my three dimensional array as such but I still get back an error:

```
incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
```

I thought I had indicated that my values were doubles and all the variables are pulled from this class... maybe I'm missing something fundamental?

So:

1. can someone point out why this code isn't working? and
2. is there an easier or faster way to approach this problem?

I started with a 3D array that should contain my xyz coordinates, though I am open to alternate ways to store my data. The coordinates have at least 3 decimal places (0.000). 
 
I am creating new points using nested for loops and if the new point meets a specific condition, I want these new xyz coordinates to be added to the array. Here's my code so far:

```
public class foo{
    double x = 25, y = 25, z = 25;
     double i, j, k, rx, ry, rz, dist;
     double rmin=0.1-0.01, rmax = 0.1+0.01;
     double ngrid;
     double nmax = 100000; 
     double xgrid, ygrid, zgrid;   

public void gridCoors(){    

double[][][] threeD = new double [rx][ry][rz];
 for (ngrid = 0 ; ngrid < nmax ; ngrid++){ 

     for (i = -x ; i < x; i++) {

                rx = i*0.01;

                for(j = -y; j < y; j++){

                    ry = j*0.01;

                    for(k = -z; k < z; k++){

                        rz = z*0.01;

                        dist = sqrt(rx*rx + ry*ry + rz*rz);

if (dist > rmin && dist < rmax){
       xgrid = rx;
       ygrid = ry;
       zgrid = rz;


       threeD.add(new gridCoors(rx,ry,rz));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)**
I think that size of the arrays should be int

```
double[][][] threeD = new double [rx][ry][rz];
```

change type of **rx,ry,rz** from double to int it should help.

---

**Proof:**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4 
It says:

> Arrays must be indexed by int values; short, byte, or char values may also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary numeric promotion...

---

**And now little hint to point 2)**
***There are many approaches of solving this problem***, in my opinion, it would be more readable using List type of let's say XYZ class.

And then you could create a class that contains a definition of coordinates later using proper constructor you could add new objects of XYZ to list of XYZ class type.

```
class XYZ{

 double x, y, z;      

 XYZ(double x, double y, double z){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}
```

And then you could expand this class with some methods useful for you. Or leave it as "definition of your object" only for saving data.
Working in object-oriented language it's a good practice to use it's objectivity.